# Tab Host does not carry through out application in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am new to android programming.My application consists of nearly 20 screens and with bottum tab host with three tab items.this Tab host should be carried to each and every screen.But in my application it is carried upto two activities.Then how can I carries through out the application.

This is the code what I wrote

```
Resources ressources = getResources(); 
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
// Android tab
Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, AndroidActivity.class);
TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost.newTabSpec("Android").setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_android_config));
        tabSpecAndroid.setContent(intentAndroid);
// Apple tab
Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, AppleActivity.class);
TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabHost
.newTabSpec("Apple")
.setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_apple_config))
.setContent(intentApple);
// Windows tab
Intent intentWindows = new Intent().setClass(this, WindowsActivity.class);
TabSpec tabSpecWindows = tabHost
.newTabSpec("Windows")
.setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_windows_config))
.setContent(intentWindows);
// Blackberry tab
Intent intentBerry = new Intent().setClass(this, BlackBerryActivity.class);
TabSpec tabSpecBerry = tabHost
.newTabSpec("Berry")
.setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_blackberry_config))
.setContent(intentBerry);
// add all tabs 
tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);
tabHost.addTab(tabSpecApple);
tabHost.addTab(tabSpecWindows);
tabHost.addTab(tabSpecBerry);
```

In first screen we have list of entries.When I click on one of the entry,it goes to another screen.but In that another screen tab host is not appearing.Any thing wrong in my code.Please give me suggestion.

Thanks inadvance

Comment: what do you mean by carry through?

Comment: Explain bit more provide some code or how teh navigation is happening and also the tabhost implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use fragments.

See this tutorial

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-navigation-tabs-using-tabhost-and-fragments-in-android/